# Select only a portion of a column

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, razor

Looking for a way to do this in LINQ/Razor/Entity/CSS.

I will pull the data this way.

```
db.TPGForumPosts.OrderBy (p => p.dateCreated).First()
```

I am building a new feed from a forum announcements table.

This column will have coded HTML in it, will I only be able to pull a portion of it to show on my new feed, or will I have to pull all of it because it will have/display HTML elements which if I only pull some of it could result in unclosed tags.

If I do have to pull all of it which I am assuming I do, is there a way to only show a portion of it in my news feed?

Example:

```
<p>
    This is a very long repeating repeating repeating repeating repeating
    repeating repeating repeating repeating repeating repeating repeating repeating
    repeating repeating repeating repeating repeating repeating repeating repeating
    repeating repeating repeating repeating repeating paragraph.
</p>
```

So my news ticker would only pull the first 50 chars.

```
<p> This is a very long repeating repeating repeating repeating repeating.
```

But that would result in an unclosed `<p>` tag.

Is there a way to pull it all but only display a portion of it in my news feed?

Comment: Is the HTML code always in the same format?

Comment: No, it is pulled from a WYSIWYG editor and will differ every time. @ataravati

Comment: Is it an option to just limit the size of where you are rendering it via CSS?

Comment: @Brocco Any option that works is what I am looking for.  I don't mind pulling the entire column if I can use CSS to only show a portion of it.

Comment: The example @ataravati has below is exactly what I was referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is to display the HTML inside a `<span>`, and use CSS to style it like below to hide the extra text:

```
.myClass {
    display:inline-block;
    width:180px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

In your View:

```
<span class = "myClass">
  // your html goes here
</span>
```